# Write down an equation for paths with the following image sets

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

i) The triangle with the corners $1,-1+i,-1-i$ where the initial point and final point is $1$.

ii) The union of two circles with radius $1$ and centers $i$ and $-i$, where the initial and final point is zero.

Here is what I have so far

i) By using the definition of path concatenation I have defined $\gamma(t)$ as $\gamma_{1}(t)= (1-t)1+(-1+i)t$  for $t \in [0,1]$

$\gamma_{2}(t)=(1-t)(-1+i)+(-1-i)t$ for $t \in [1,2]$

$\gamma_{3}(t)=(1-t)(-1-i)+t$ for $t \in [2,3]$

ii) I have done the same for this and defined $\gamma(t)$ as

$\gamma_{1}(t)=i+e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$

$\gamma_{2}(t)=-i+e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$

I am pretty sure that the equations are right but I'm not sure about the interval for to and how to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

i) is correct.

ii) is also almost fine, excepct the interval in your last line, it should rather be 
$$t\in [2\pi,4\pi]$$,
and you should guarantee that $\gamma_1(0)=\gamma_2(2\pi)=0$. Note that $e^{ti}$ is starting the circle from the point $1$ (if $t=0$), but for $\gamma_1$ you should start it on $-i$, so  $i-ie^{it}$ will be the one.